# Alteração de Campos em Banco de Dados

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Oi! Criei um banco de dados com uma tabela de `Treinamentos` que possui `Nome`, `Validade` e `Status` como campos, porém quando a data atual passa da data de validade o campo `status`, que é `1` para ativo e `0` para inativo, precisa se alterar para `0`.

Estou tendo dificuldades para fazer esse procedimento automaticamente, e vi que posso fazer isso tanto no banco quanto com php na página web que estou criando, porém ainda não tive sucesso. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode criar uma rotina PHP para isso:

```
mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE Treinamentos SET status = 0 WHERE DATE(NOW()) >= Validade");
```

Comment: Funcionou, obg!

Comment: Marque como resposta correta!A @ThiagoVieira